# Send image to a contact with a single click via Whatsapp from a laptop

Tags: automation, whatsapp

I have a requirement to send 100 different Whatsapp images to 100 different Users every week.

For E.g:

C:/image/img1.jpg needs to be sent to  +919999999999

C:/image/img2.jpg needs to be sent to  +919999999991

.
.

And So on.

Is there any automated way I can do this?

Comment: Cynical observation: Is someone writing an app to send spam to WhatsApp users? E.g. If that 100 was actually 100m. And did you really need to give a real telephone number as part of the question?

Comment: HI, It's just a random telephone number.

Comment: HI, It's just a random telephone number, ill change it in the question thou. 
Also, I am maintaining the timetable for various Professors. I create the timetable for each professor and save the image of that as JPG. 
As of now, I am manually copying pasting the images to individual users.  As as for the spammer, they don't need to send different images to different Users .